# Is there a Jewish principle: "To sleep on a big decision"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, mesorah-tradition, chazal

In Anglo society, there is the principle to "sleep on" a big decision before pulling the trigger on it. (Be it a large purchase, a business deal, or other substantial decision in work or personal life.)

Is such a practice or principle described by Chazal, the Gemarra or other sources in the Jewish tradition?

Comment: Sanhedrin 4:1 (via Sefaria) "In cases of capital law, the court may conclude the deliberations and issue the ruling even on that same day to acquit the accused, but must wait until the following day to find him liable."

Comment: Add to that הֱווּ מְתוּנִים בַּדִּין from Pirkei Avot 1:1

Comment: The Prophet Eliyahu states “How long will you keep hopping between two opinions?" (1 Kings 18:21). Rashi explains that "two concepts" refers to "two thoughts, because you do not know how to decide". Also, the Gemara (Chagigah 3b) states "make your ears like a funnel and acquire for yourself an understanding heart to hear both the statements [...]". So, I think that according to this Gemara, you should acquire all the information you need to make an decision

Comment: מה שלא יעשה השכל יעשה הזמן

Comment: @GershonGold That is nice, but on the allegorical side...? (And where is it from?)

Comment: @jonesome reinstate Monica  - don't know where this is from. It is a saying my grandmother always said. That is why I put it as a comment.

Comment: @GershonGold Love it.  Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be linked to the first Mishna in the 4th chapter of Sanhedrin, regarding the decision for a capital law.It's called "Halanat Hadin" the withhoding of the judgment. See Gemara 17a, 34a and 35a.

Below the quote from the Mishnah.

> דִּינֵי מָמוֹנוֹת גּוֹמְרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם בֵּין לִזְכוּת בֵּין לְחוֹבָה, דִּינֵי נְפָשׁוֹת גּוֹמְרִין בּוֹ בַיּוֹם לִזְכוּת וּבְיוֹם שֶׁלְּאַחֲרָיו לְחוֹבָה, לְפִיכָךְ אֵין דָּנִין לֹא בְעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת וְלֹא בְעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב:‏

> In cases of capital law, the court may conclude the deliberations and issue the ruling even on that same day to acquit the accused, but must wait until the following day to find him liable. Therefore, since capital cases might continue for two days, the court does not judge cases of capital law on certain days, neither on the eve of Shabbat nor the eve of a Festival.

Comment: @rosend sorry, I just saw you answered in your comment. If you want, I can delete my answer.

Comment: There is no need to delete, see the following by our master and teacher Reb Isaac: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5231/11501 and https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4280/11501